# Pubsub emulator resend the acknowledged messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I created a subscriber client to listen to messages from pubsub emulator. When I published more than 500 messages to pubsub. The subscriber client still received the messages, although those messages are acknowledged already.

I am using python 3.

There are 3 classes:

Class A: the subscriber client to listen to messages from pubsub emulator

Class B: the object for storing message to cloud storage

Class C: the object for extracting and inserting the message into SQL tables

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import B
import C

class A(object):
    def receive_messages(self,project_id, subscription_name):

        subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
                            project_id, subscription_name)

        def callback(message):
            print('Received message: {}'.format(message))

            B_obj = B()
            storing_status = B_obj.storing_to_cloud_drive()

            if storing_status:
                message.ack()
                print('Message is acked')

                C_obj = C()
                C_obj.extract_and_insert_to_sql_table()

            else:
                message.nack()
                print('Message is nacked')

        subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

        print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
        while True:
            time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: How are you verifying that you are successfully acking messages and seeing those acked messages get redelivered? Is it possible that duplicate messages are being generated on the publish side? Duplicate messages are possible in real Cloud Pub/Sub, especially if you are nacking, since an entire batch may be redelivered if one message in the batch is nacked. However, this is unexpected behavior for the emulator.

Comment: @Lauren, thank you for your response. I thought it is the Pubsub emulator issue. When I removed all logic, just did receive, ack the message, and print out "Message is acked". I published 1000 messages, and the Pubsub emulator was still sending the acknowledged messages. I hope the real Pubsub will work better than the emulator one.